# Apps Script web app error: can't find file

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to create an Apps Script web app for a project, but the URL it gives me always redirects and Drive says that it can't find the file.
What am I missing?

e.g. `script.google.com/macros/s/id/exec` redirects to `script.google.com/macros/u/1/s/id/exec`

Comment: Your question is missing a [mcve]

Comment: Are you in any chance logged to multiple accounts? Try opening it in incognito.

Comment: I am logged in to  multiple accounts, but it doesn't work no matter what settings it is set to for who can access.

Comment: I have provided an answer @2pichar, kindly check if that works out on you

Comment: I created a test project and set it up as a web app on a different account, and that works. Both projects have the same settings, just on a different account. What's going on?

Comment: I have included the reason and solution with their respective sources on the answer below @2pichar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it in incognito and log only 1 account or log out other accounts in your normal browser and only leave the one that has access to said script.

Redirecting to `u/1` means that you have most likely logged in at least 2 accounts.

As what was said by a google developer:

> Multi-login has never been supported in Apps Script and given the vast number of features and services provided by Apps Script, multi-login becomes pretty significant change with a lot of risks involved.

> Our team plans to begin to work on multi-login support for the new Apps Script IDE and container-bound scripts in Q3 ‘21.

> For Google Add-ons, google.script.run, and Web Apps, existing workarounds include:

> Signing out of all accounts and using only 1 account: or
> Using an incognito tab to sign in

#### Reference:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374#comment292
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/projects#fix_issues_with_multiple_google_accounts

Comment: That was it. So for some reason, it was the fact that it was redirecting caused the issue. When I opened it on incognito, it didn't redirect and loaded correctly.